Mice 2l.pan method giving a bimodal distribution for skewed variable
I am working with an imputed dataset, and I am unsure if the imputation method for one of for one of my variables is suitable. I have several variables across 2 timepoints. I am using the mice package and the 2l.pan method for this variable currently. It is highly left skewed, and the imputation seems to be pushing towards a bimodal distribution. The density plots for these 2 variables (acc_1b_ltr and acc_1b_sptl) are attached. I also used the miceadds 2l.pmm method for them, which seemed to avoid this, however I get the warning.

acc_1b_ltr boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

Any recommendations of other methods to use here? Or could this warning be ignored? Thanks!
e
